# Get count of Specific Values from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array and i want to get the count of specific values.

The Structure is as:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [coupon_id] => 350
        [coupon_title] => This is the title of coupons
        [coupon_code] => ABCD
        [coupon_type] => coupon
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [coupon_id] => 350
        [coupon_title] => This is the title of coupons
        [coupon_code] => ABCD
        [coupon_type] => no_coupon
    )
)
```

Now i want to get the count of `coupon` and `no_coupon`

I tried by `array_value_count` but i am getting this can only count STRING and VALUES.

Comment: `array_value_count(array_column('coupon_type'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
# Get the data from where you want to get the count
$array  = array(
    array('coupon_type' => 'coupon'),
    array('coupon_type' => 'no_coupon')
);

# Count the variables
$count = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'coupon_type')));

print_r($count);
// Will show
// Array ( [coupon] => 1 [no_coupon] => 1 )
?>
```

Comment: @mohit -   Do you want the sum, or the numbers of occurrences.  I believe `array_count_values` returns the number of times that key is present in the array and not the sum of it's values.  Never-mind it's the number of times the value is in the array...  So this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop for this purpose.

```
      $count_coupon=0;
      $count_no_coupon=0; 

      foreach ( $array as $arr )
      {
      if( $arr['coupon_type'] == 'coupon' )
       {
         $count_coupon++;
       }

       else if( $arr['coupon_type'] == 'no_coupon' )      
       {
         $count_no_coupon++;
       }
```